# How to query selection of cells in two columns alternatly hidden or replaced with character

Tags: sql

Good morning everybody.
I am creating the form which will help my children to learn English words.  To achieve that  data table should be displayed in a specific way. The application will generate the table of the words in English and in polish alternately hidden. Below there is an example.

Table with data

ID | English| Polish 
1   | apple  | jabłko
2   | fruit  | owoc
3   | head   | głowa
4   | arm    | ręka
5   | leg    | noga
6   | table  | stół
7   | chair  | krzesło
8   | phone  | telefon

Table data with odd and even cells alternately replaced with * or hidden

ID | English| Polish 
1   | *                    | jabłko
2   | fruit          |*
3   | *                   | głowa
4   | arm          | *
5   | *                   | noga
6   | table      | *
7   | *                   | krzesło
8   | phone   |*

How to achieve result showed in the table above?

Best regards
polix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it dependent upon the ID: when it's even, show English, and when it's odd show Polish.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CASE (ID % 2) WHEN 1 THEN Enlish ELSE '***' END,
    CASE (ID % 2) WHEN 0 THEN Polish ELSE '***' END

FROM
    Translations
```

Answer (score 1):

I would that in code, not in Sql. That is, I would select every column from the table, and then alternatively hide with stars (*) the English or Polish field in your favorite programming language. That would allow you to check if the given answer is correct or not.

Anyhow if you want to do that in Sql, then:

```
select
    id,
    IF(id%2=0, eword, '*'),
    IF(id%2<>0, pword, '*')
from
    dictionary;
```